# Geocoding several addresses in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geocoding, excel, address

I am using QGIS and I have an Excel file that has fields with direction and it fails to geocode these addresses.

Examples:

```
address                apartment     township
1 calle 2 avenida      Guatemala     Escuintla
4 calle 5 avenida      Guatemala     Santa rosa
```

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

There are some plugins for geocoding in QGIS. Simplest one is [GeoCoding](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeoCoding/), it can also reverse geocode.

If you have csv file and want to geocode multiple addresses in one go then I would suggest you to go for [MMQGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/), It is a multi-purpose plugin which include geocoding as well. It takes CSV as input.

I would suggest you to make your file in such a manner that it is easily readable and understandable. There must be columns for Name, Address/Street Address, City and Country.